# Problema na Query SQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e utilizo um BD em MySql. Numa parte do sistema, preciso incrementar o estoque de um determinado produto, teste o comando no Workbench e funcionou de boa, mas quando executo esse comando dentro do visual studio me retorna erro. Segue o código

```
// Abre a conexão
mConn.Open();

//Query SQL
MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE estoque SET quantidade_estoque = quantidade_estoque + $'"+ txtQuantidade.Text +"' WHERE produto_estoque = '"+ cmbbProduto.Text +"')", mConn);

//Executa a Query SQL
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Fecha a conexão
mConn.Close();
```

E o erro é o seguinte:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''500' WHERE produto_estoque =
>   'Produto')' at line 1'

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: checou os tipos de dados? `produto_estoque` pode ser um id e tá passando um texto..

Answer (score 0):

Boas pelo que entendi o campo “quantidade_estoque” é um numérico e estais a tentar incrementar somando-a a uma string. ($'"+ txtQuantidade.Text +"')
A minha sugestão é alterares a query para o seguinte:

```
MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE estoque SET quantidade_estoque = quantidade_estoque + " +  int.Parse(txtQuantidade.Text) + " WHERE produto_estoque = '" + cmbbProduto.Text + "')", mConn);
```

Comment: Então, eu já havia tentado passar dessa forma mas retorna o mesmo erro, com a diferença que aparentemente o Visual Studio não reconhece o valor sem o '$'.

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer debug para veres o que realmente estais a tentar enviar para a base de dados.?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de analisar com mais atenção identifiquei o erro e estava no fechamento do código da Query. Para futuras referências caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, o código que funcionou foi:
 // Abre a conexão
            mConn.Open();

```
        //Query SQL
        MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE estoque SET quantidade_estoque = quantidade_estoque + " + int.Parse(txtQuantidade.Text) + " WHERE produto_estoque = '" + cmbbProduto.Text + "'", mConn);

        //Executa a Query SQL
        command2.ExecuteReader();
```